# Formatting JSX into the render with array map function

Tags: reactjs

```js
let typeOpt = [];
let specialityOpt = [];
let planOpt = [];
let acceptOpt = [];
let officeOpt = [];
let doctorOpt = [];

<div>
    {typeOpt.map((typeOp,index) => (
       <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={typeOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>
    ))}
</div>
<div>
    {specialityOpt.map((specialityOp,index) => (
       <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={specialityOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>
    ))}
</div>
<div>
{planOpt.map((planOp,index) => {
    <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={planOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>

  })}
  {acceptOpt.map((acceptOp,index) => {
    <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={acceptOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>


  })}
   {officeOpt.map((officeOp,index) => {
    <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={officeOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>

  })}

</div>
<div>
{doctorOpt.map((doctorOp,index) => (
   <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checkedItem}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
              value="checkedB"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={doctorOp.label}
        />

      </FormGroup>

  ))}
</div>
```

Following are the code snippet .
Here initially there are 6 different array and assume that all the array contains the various data into that.

And the rest of the code inside the render function.

Could some one let me know how to format the JSX code as there are lots of 
duplication of the code.

How to write only one FormGroup and FormControlLabel and give it into the different array and onClick wodul return the checkBox name and id of that particular id.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
let arrays = ['typeOpt','specialityOpt',...]

{ arrays.map((itemOpt) => (
<div>
    {itemOpt.map((itemOp,index) => (
    <FormGroup row>

        <FormControlLabel
        control={
            <Checkbox
            checked={this.state.checkedItem}
            onChange={this.handleChange('checkedItem')}
            value="checkedB"
            color="primary"
            />
        }
        label={itemOp.label}
        />

    </FormGroup>
    ))}
</div>
)}
```